# How to get streaming home timeline from Twitter in PHP?

Tags: php, twitter, streaming

How do I display my own streaming Twitter home timeline with PHP? So that the connection remains open indefinitely?

I have a Twitter application and all the required keys and tokens.

I've been going over the Twitter documentation and playing around with several PHP libraries, but to no avail. I haven't found anything like a step-by-step tutorial, either.

Thanks!

Comment: This really seems to be an elusive topic. The most explanatory article I found so far - http://af-design.com/blog/2010/12/17/reading-the-twitter-stream-api-with-php/ - is outdated: the streaming API now only uses OAuth...

Answer (score 0):

Twitter provides a useful widget for this (displayed as an iFrame on your website)

log into twitter(in your web browser), Click the gear>settings>widgets then you can configure it to search for @yourtwitterhandle or #yourhashtag or both.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not exactly what I'm looking for. I'm really trying to get the raw data stream and then do with it whatever I want.

Comment: to get an active data stream (not restful) I believe you need access to the twitter firehose... not a very cheap option. Your best option is to make multiple restful queries using a cron job and storing the result in your database - even then you may run into twitter's unpublished query limit (unpublished and not constant from user to user)